# Ошибка: "PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol TABLE", при запуске анонимного PL/SQL блока с DDL различных таблиц

Tags: python, sql, oracle, plsql, cx-oracle

Запускаю следуюший скрипт:

```
import cx_Oracle
    
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user = db_user, password = db_pwd, dsn = 'TULSA').
cur = conn.cursor()

sql = ("""  
        BEGIN
            truncate table shop_ord_temp;
            truncate table shop_ord_item_temp;
            truncate table shop_cust_temp;
        END;
    """)

cur.execute(sql)
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Получаю ошибку при запуске анонимного блока:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 15, in <module>
    cur.execute(sql)
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-06550: line 3, column 22:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "TABLE" when expecting one of the following:
    
       := . ( @ % ;
```

В чём причиа ошибки, или как сделать лучше?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Truncating multiple tables in a Oracle PL/SQL block fails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63728178) от участника [@epipko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1549571/epipko)</sub>

Truncating multiple tables in a Oracle PL/SQL block fails

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/63728178

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте так:

```
sql = ("""  
        BEGIN
            execute immediate 'truncate table shop_ord_temp';
            execute immediate 'truncate table shop_ord_item_temp';
            execute immediate 'truncate table shop_cust_temp';
        END;
    """)
```

Это функция PL/SQL, не имеющая прямого отношения к Python.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63733207) от участника [@Christopher Jones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4799035/christopher-jones)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае, не будет заметного выигрыша в производительности, заключив несколько динамических DDL команд в анонимный блок. Разница во временных затратах между одним обращением по сети вместо нескольких в случае отдельных запросов, по сравнению с затратами на другие операции, таких как парсинг и выполнение самих DDL, ничтожно мала.

Поэтому, следующий воспроизводимый пример более лаконичен и удобочитаем:

```
from cx_Oracle import connect 

conn = connect ('me/me@dbsrv/dbsrvc', encoding="utf-8")
cur = conn.cursor()

tables = ['shop_ord_temp','shop_ord_item_temp','shop_cust_temp']
truncate = 'truncate table '
for table in tables:  
    cur.execute (truncate + table)
print ("tables truncated", len (tables))
cur.close ()
conn.close ()
```

Comment: Это решение мне нравится больше)

Comment: @MaxU Мне тоже ;) Кстати, автор соседнего ответа [продукт менеджер](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/efficient-and-scalable-batch-statement-execution-in-python-cx_oracle) в Oracle. Что-то он не совсем внимательно отнёсся к вопросу.